# Apache Tomcat 8 Exception - org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value

Tags: java, java-8, tomcat8, spring-framework-beans

I recently built an application (which works fine when built with Java 1.7 and using Tomcat 7) with JDK1.8 and trying to deploy the war under Tomcat 8 when I face  the below issues during start-up.

Logs:

```
13-Mar-2019 08:52:57.059 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xyzJmsTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'weblogic.jms.client.JMSXAConnectionFactory' to required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' for property 'connectionFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [weblogic.jms.client.JMSXAConnectionFactory] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'connectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:638)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'weblogic.jms.client.JMSXAConnectionFactory' to required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' for property 'connectionFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [weblogic.jms.client.JMSXAConnectionFactory] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'connectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:464)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:489)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1465)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [weblogic.jms.client.JMSXAConnectionFactory] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'connectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:267)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:449)
    ... 30 more
```

UPDATE:
I removed JMS API jars and now I see the below error in logs

```
13-Mar-2019 09:28:21.881 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletTransportFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (2) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'bus' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xyzConnectionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory]
PropertyAccessException 2: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'transportIds' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xyzConnectionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
```

Comment: Just exclude JMS API jars from your deployment, and the error should be gone.

Comment: Please add the source code snippet in a question ?  from the error we could see you have Bean which is using `connectionFactory` . On Bean init() the type is not able to find out the connectionFactory.

Comment: In the applicationContext.xml I have the below
<!-- JMS Connection factory -->
 <bean id="xyzConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiTemplate">
   <ref bean="xyzJndiTemplate" />
  </property>
  <property name="jndiName">
   <value>${xyz.broker.connectionFactory}</value>
  </property>
 </bean>